# Is it possible to plot std_msgs/Bool.msg in rqt_plot?

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to plot a 1 or 0 for a topic that posts std_msgs/Bool.msg

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196366/is-it-possible-to-plot-std_msgs/bool.msg-in-rqt_plot?/) by [GGabria](https://answers.ros.org/users/19837/ggabria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its not possible. Field types are only integer or float types. See its code is

here https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/groovy-devel/rqt_plot/src/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0